# OpenSwan + AWS + Ubuntu 14.04 - Cannot reach server

Tags: ubuntu, vpn, amazon-web-services, openswan

i'm currently trying to set up a VPN in order to login into a private subnet hosted on AWS.
The target host has Ubuntu 14.04 and installed OpenSwan.

I've setup ipsec.conf, ipsec.secrets, xl2tpd.conf, options.xl2tpd and chap-secrets and currently ipsec and xl2tpd are running on server.

*ipsec verify* will return no errors.

I've created a PSK session on Mac OS X pointing to an elastic IP (54.187.107, which is attached to the VPN Instance), pasted the shared secret, but when trying to login with my user and password i will get a "The L2TP-VPN server did not respond"

When checking logs, i will get these:

Myterminal# tail /var/log/ppp.log

> Fri May 16 15:46:22 2014 : L2TP connecting to server '54.187.107.160' (54.187.107.160)...
>
> > Fri May 16 15:46:22 2014 : IPSec connection started
> >
> > > Fri May 16 15:46:23 2014 : IPSec connection established
> > >
> > > > Fri May 16 15:46:43 2014 : L2TP cannot connect to the server

Myterminal# tail /var/log/system.log

> racoon[530]: IKEv1 Information-Notice: transmit success. (Delete ISAKMP-SA)
>
> racoon[530]: glob found no matches for path "/var/run/racoon/*.conf"
>
> racoon[530]: pfkey DELETE failed: No such file or directory
>
> racoon[530]: Connecting.
>
> racoon[530]: Unknown Informational exchange received.

Furthermore , i have used tcpdump and checked ports 1701, 4500 and 500. Only 1701 is not receiving packets/data.

If you need further information from the configuration files please let me know, it's been a few days and still cannot reach the server. My apologies if the post lacks a proper format for the code, i'm currently learning how to do it.

Regards